# RecyclerView within CardView center_vertical

Tags: android, android-layout, center, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Hello I have a RecyclerView within CardView. 
I want the Text of RecyclerView to be in center_vertical within CardView.

CardView xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/item_breakfast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/item_breakfast_height"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/item_breakfast_corner">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- Icon breakfast -->
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/breakfast_icon"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/item_breakfast_circleViewSize"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/item_breakfast_circleViewSize"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list_food"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/breakfast_icon"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The RecyclerView xm is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <!-- Food  -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/food"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The TextView with id "food" isn't center_Vertical. Why?

Comment: `android:layout_gravity="center"` apply this parameter to your `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

Use `layout_gravity` to center the `TextView` inside the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <!-- Food  -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/food"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> This code may help you to resolve your issue.Change or modify your code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_breakfast"
      card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/item_breakfast_corner">



      <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <!-- Icon breakfast -->
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/breakfast_icon"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/item_breakfast_circleViewSize"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/item_breakfast_circleViewSize"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list_food"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/breakfast_icon"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```